# swapoff/swapon when script is running

Tags: php, memory, swap, swapfile

Sometime the swap memory hit 100% and the running script (PHP) is considerably slower. I'd like to ask in which scenario it is okay to  run the command `swapoff -a ; swapon -a` to clear up the swap memory so that the running script is not affected, and in which scenario is it affected?

Comment: Never. Just don't do that.

Comment: `swapon/swapoff` = root access so don't do that

Comment: @RC why you mentioned about the root access? I'm running the application in my personal computer so there is no security concern.